# Go GoCILint, Flag error assignment to Blank Identifier

Tags: go, static-analysis, lint

I have started using GoCILint, but it does not flag code where the error is assigned to blank identifier.

```
func someFunc() error{

}

_ := someFunc()
```

this is an incorrect coding practice where the error is being assigned to Blank Identifier and not checked, but this is not getting flagged by GoCILint.

Is this a limitation with the lints or do I have to enable something here

I have checked the errchk, govet, staticanalysis lint tools but none of them seems to be flagging this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[errcheck](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck) accepts blank assignments by default (this is intentional).

However, you can tell it to trigger on `_` assignments with the `-blank` flag.

This is documented in the [Use](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck#use) section of the `errcheck` documentation:

> The -blank flag enables checking for assignments of errors to the
>   blank identifier. It takes no arguments.

At the golang-ci level, this can be specified in the [config file](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#config-file):

```
linters-settings:
  ...
  errcheck:
    ...
    # report about assignment of errors to blank identifier: `num, _ := strconv.Atoi(numStr)`;
    # default is false: such cases aren't reported by default.
    check-blank: false
    ...
```